# Multiple aliased pages for same taxonomy term (e.g. blog/term1 and images/term1)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels, path-aliases

I have some taxonomy vocabularies that are used on different content types (blog posts, images, businesses etc.).

I want to create a main page for each content type listing, and filter those listings by taxonomy terms, creating multiple aliased pages.

For example:

1. BLOG:

   - main blog page listing all blog posts and some related blocks @ /blog
   - blog sub-pages for each vocabulary/term listing blog posts with that term @ /blog/vocabulary/term
2. ACTIVITIES:

   - main page listing all businesses @ /activities
   - activities sub-pages for each vocabulary/term applied to the businesses @activies/vocabulary/term

The problem I am having is to have aliases and metatags set automatically using the taxonomy data.

I would like "content-type/vocabulary/term" (not "vocabulary/term/content-type"), and to still be able to use "vocabulary/term" (default Views or Panels taxonomy term templates) as general pages listing all content types.

Is this possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with dynamically creating every page is with the "content type", Drupal does not support dynamic arguments (wildcards) as the first part of a path, so there really isn't much you can do about that.

But let's approach it a little different, actually you should be able to use the taxonomy view that comes disabled with views by default to achieve what you are looking for, I would create a new page and:

- enable it
- create a contextual filter "Content: Type"
- add relationship "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" and require it
- add contextual filter "Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name" using the relationship
- rearrange the contextual filters: "content type", "vocabulary", "term id(with depth)", term id("depth modifier")
- edit "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)", in the section for "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED" change "Filter Value Type" to "term name"
- edit the path for the page (browse/%/%/%)

save your view and that should do it.

Again, remember that we can't use a dynamic path argument as the first part of a path in drupal which is why I added "browse".

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
Will I be able to use the taxonomy terms metatags on those pages?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I haven't ever tried... are you using metatags provided by a module?

Comment: I'm using metatag module. I am trying to make the view, still no success, updating asap

Comment: Ok. The page exists, with the right path, but no results are shown (while there is content with terms).. 
Also, no metatags are set.

Comment: I just walked through with the exact instructions above on a new installation and it worked fine.